# Нужно, чтобы страница полностью помещалась по высоте на разных мониторах

Tags: css

Нужно, чтобы страница полностью помещалась по высоте на разных мониторах (без прокрутки). 
Чтобы при изменении высоты монитора, страница меняла масштаб и опять полностью заполняла экран. 
По ширине все получается с помощью *CSS3*. 
P.S. Шапка с фиксированной высотой (*position:fixed*), 1 блок,подвал с *position:absolute*. 
Нужно чтобы помещалась на мониторах, скажем от *920px* и до *1920px*. 
Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: У Вас будет только один блок ? или несколько ?

Comment: @Maks Devda Шапка с фиксированной высотой (position fixed), 1 блок,подвал с position absolute. Нужно чтобы помещалась на мониторах, скажем от 920px и до 1920px Спасибо за ответы.

css

Comment: @Maks Devda Шапка с фиксированной высотой (position fixed), 1 блок,подвал с position absolute. Нужно чтобы помещалось по высоте на мониторах, скажем от 1260 х 875 и до 1920 х 1080 Спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идет о том, чтобы растянуть блок с контентом по ширине.высоте экрана, то можно так:

html:

```
<div class = "content">Тут контент</div>
```

css:

```
.content{
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
}
```

пример на [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kh92j116/)

Если вопрос про то, как так сверстать контент, чтобы он всегда помещался внутри экрана, то вам надо сначала ответить для себя на вопрос - какое поведение от страницы вы ожидаете, скажем при разрешении 1200 на 200 пикселей, а при 200 на 1200? Если вам все еще хочется, чтобы все помещалось, то вам стоит отслеживать в js соотношение сторон экрана и скейлить контент программно.

Comment: Шапка с фиксированной высотой (position fixed), 1 блок,подвал с position absolute. Нужно чтобы помещалась на мониторах, скажем от 920px и до 1920px Спасибо за ответы.

css

Comment: @Miki  Шапка с фиксированной высотой (position fixed), 1 блок,подвал с position absolute. Нужно чтобы помещалось по высоте на мониторах, скажем от 1260 х 875  и до 1920 х 1080 Спасибо за ответы.